# Can't change Android Alert Dialog Button Color

Tags: android, xml, button, colors, android-alertdialog

Although I tried the following codes, I am unable to change the color of my alert dialog which is red in any case.

Java:

```
    private void showAlertDialog(String title, String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Tamam", null);
    builder.show();
}
```

XML:

```
    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <!--item name="android:background">@color/google_orange</item-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/google_orange</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@color/google_orange</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/google_orange</item>
    <item name="colorError">@color/google_orange</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/google_orange</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, just solved. The problem was I used android.app.AlertDialog instead of androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog. I don't know why but the code below doesn't work for the first one.
This does the trick if you use the second:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/google_orange</item>
</style>
```

The Java code stays the same as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce the issue you posted: 'Can't change Android Alert Dialog Button Color'. The use of 'colorButtonNormal' changes the button's color.

Comment: yes, it should have but unfortunately not in my case and I couldn't understand the reason

Comment: and also I believe this should be a comment rather than being an answer

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks for the heads-up. New user here, did not notice the small greyed-out wordings 'add a comment'.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work!!

```
     private void showAlertDialog(String title, String message){
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
      builder.setTitle(title);
      builder.setMessage(message);
      builder.setPositiveButton("Tamam", null);
      builder.setOnShowListener( new OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(...) {
            builder.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(COLOR_YOU_WANT);
         }
        });

      builder.show();
   }
```

Comment: builder does not have a method called "setOnShowListener"